# NHibernate identity : int or long

Tags: c#, nhibernate, identity

I begin my NHibernate mapping. In major cases I use int type but for some entities I need to persist million of objets. Is long type for identity will be the best choice ?

Answer (score 5):

`Int32` (or just `int`) is fine for "millions."  You only need to start thinking about `Int64` (`long`) if you will have *billions* of rows.

A signed `int` can support IDs up to 2,147,483,647.

See [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Int will work for values up to 2,147,483,647.  That should be fine for "millions of objects."

For data ranges, see the [Integral Types Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w(VS.80).aspx).  If you really need more, you could use uint.